# Database doesn't exist, the other file it works

Tags: php, mysql

this is really weird and I don't know why it is like this. I have my other files work fine (login, registration, and memberadd) however, on memberaddprocess file, when it try to connect to the database, it says that my database doesn't exist. The other works fine, only the memberadd process. If anyone knows why, please kindly explain.

This is my memberadd.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/chtml-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web Programming :: Assignment 2" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Web, programming" />
    <title>Member Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Member System</h1>

</body>
</html>

<?php
require_once('sqlconnect.inc.php');


if(isset($_SESSION['membername'] ))
    {

    echo "".$_SESSION['membername']."<p>Add Member Page</p>";


$conn = @mysqli_connect($host, 
        $user, 
        $pswd, 
        $dbnm);

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "<p>Database connection failure</p>"; 
    } else {

    @mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbnm)
        or die ("Database not available");
    }

    $memberHid = $_SESSION['membername'];

    $query = "SELECT member_name FROM team";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(!$result) {
        echo "<p>Query failed to execute, Error with: ",    $query, "</p>";
        } 

    $queryFetch = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    //echo "<p> $queryResult1</p>"; 
    $m=0;
    while($queryFetch)
    {
    $mQueryFetch[$m] = $queryFetch[0];
    $queryFetch = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $m++;
    }
    $i=0;
    $query2 = "SELECT member_id 
                FROM team 
                WHERE member_name='$memberHid'";

    $result2 = @mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $queryFetchResult = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $memId = $queryFetchResult[0];

    $query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM myteam 
               WHERE member_id1 = '$memId'"; //query for counting the no of friends 

    $resultSelect = @mysqli_query($conn,$query3)
                or die ("<p>Query failed to execute.</p>". "<p>Error with:" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn))."</p>";

    $arCount = mysqli_fetch_row($resultSelect); 
                echo "<p>Number of Current team member is"." ". $arCount[0]."  "."</p>";

    $querySelect = "SELECT member_id2 FROM myteam WHERE member_id1 = '$memId'";

    $resultSelect2 = @mysqli_query($conn, $querySelect);
    $memArr = mysqli_fetch_row($resultSelect2);
    if($memArr)
    {
        while($memArr)
        {
            foreach($memArr as $value)
                {
                    $querySelect3 = "SELECT member_name
                                     FROM team
                                     WHERE member_id = '$value'";

                    $queryResult = @mysqli_query($conn,$querySelect3);
                    $fetchArr = mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult);
                    foreach($fetchArr as $value)
                    {
                        $newDat[$a] = $value;
                        $a++;
                    }       
                }
                $memArr = mysqli_fetch_row($resultSelect2);
            }

        $curLog = array_diff($mQueryFetch, $newDat); //for displaying profile names without the currently logged in user and his old friends profile names

    $querySelect2 = "SELECT member_name 
                     FROM team;";

    $querySelectResult = @mysqli_query($conn,$querySelect2)
                        or die ("<p>Query Failed to Execute.</p>". "<p>Error with" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn))."</p>";

    echo "<table width='20%' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Member Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th></tr>";
    $fetchArray = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult);
    foreach($diff as $value)
    {
        if($value!=$_SESSION['membername'])
        {
            echo "<tr><td>{$value}</td>";
            $memberHid1 = $value;
            $memberHid = $_SESSION['membername'];
            echo "<td>"?>
            <form action ="memberaddprocess.php" method = "post" >
            <?php echo'<input type="hidden" name="memberHid1"  value="'.htmlspecialchars($memberHid1).'" />';?>
            <?php echo'<input type="hidden" name="memberHid"  value="'.htmlspecialchars($memberHid).'" />';?>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Addmember" value="AddMember" /></p>
            </form>
            <?php "</td></tr>"; 
        }
        $fetchArray = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult);
    }   
        echo"</table>";
    }
    else
    {
        $n=0;
        $querySelect2 = "SELECT member_name FROM team ; ";
        $querySelectResult = @mysqli_query($conn, $querySelect2)
                        or die ("<p>Query Failed to Execute.</p>". "<p>Error with" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn))."</p>";

        $fetchArray = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult);
        while($fetchArray)
        {
            if($fetchArray[0] != $_SESSION['membername'])
            {
                $name[$n] = $fetchArray[0];
                $n++;
            }

            $fetchArray = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult);
        }

        sort($name);
        echo "<table width='20%' border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Member Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th></tr>";

        for($n = 0; $n<sizeof($name); $n++)
        {
            $memberHid1 = $name[$n];
            $memberHid = $_SESSION['membername'];
            echo "<tr><td>{$memberHid1}</td>";
            echo "<td>"?>
            <form action ="memberaddprocess.php" method = "post" >
            <?php echo'<input type="hidden" name="memberHid1"  value="'.htmlspecialchars($memberHid1).'" />';?>
            <?php echo'<input type="hidden" name="memberHid"  value="'.htmlspecialchars($memberHid).'" />';?>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Addmember"value="AddMember" /></p>
            </form>
            <?php "</td></tr>"; 
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    echo"<p><a href='memberlist.php'>List members</a></p>";
    echo"<p><a href='logout.php'>Log out</a></p>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<p> Unauthorized access.Pls login</p>";
    echo"<p><a href='login.php'>Log in</a></p></div>";
    }



?>
```

This is my memberaddprocess.php code

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////
    session_start();
    require_once('sqlconnect.inc.php');
/////////////////////////////////////

    $memberHid1 = $_POST['memberHid1'];  
    $new_session = $_POST['memberHid']; 

    $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, 
        $user, 
        $pswd, 
        $dbnm);

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "<p>Database connection failure</p>"; 
    } else {

    @mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbnm)
        or die ("Database not available");
    }

    $query = "SELECT member_id 
              FROM team 
              WHERE member_name = '$memberHid1'";

    $queryResult = @mysqli_query($conn, $query)
                or die ("<p>Unable to execute query.</p>". "<p>Error code:" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn));

    $fetchArr = mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult);

    $memberHid3 = $fetchArr[0];             
    $memberHid = $_SESSION['membername'] = $new_session;

    $query2 = "SELECT member_id 
               FROM member 
               WHERE member_name = '$memberHid'";

    $queryResult2 = @mysqli_query($conn,$query2)
        or die ("<p>Unable to execute query.</p>". "<p>Error code" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn));

    $fetchArr2 = mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult2);
    $memberHid4 = $fetchArr2[0];

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO myteam 
               VALUES($memberHid4, $memberHid3)";

    $queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($conn,$query3)
        or die ("<p>Unable to execute query.</p>". "<p>Error code" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn))."</p>";
                echo "<p>$memberHid1"."  "." Successfully added</p>";

        $queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
                       FROM team";
        $countResult = @mysqli_query($conn,$queryCount);
        $fetchCountArr = mysqli_fetch_row($countResult);    
        for($n=0;$n<$fetchCountArr[0];$n++)
        {
            $pst = $n+1;
            $query4 = "SELECT member_id2
                        FROM myteam 
                        WHERE friend_id1 = '$pst'";

            $countResult2 = @mysqli_query($conn,$query4);
            $countArr = mysqli_fetch_row($countResult2);
            $a=0;
            while($countArr)
            {
                $a++;
                $countArr = mysqli_fetch_row($countResult2); //echo "<p>$a</p>";
            }

            $query4 = "UPDATE team 
                       SET num_of_members= '$a' 
                       WHERE member_id = '$pst' ";

            $countResult2 = @mysqli_query($conn,$query4);

        }

    $querySelect = "SELECT member_id2 
                    FROM myteam 
                    WHERE member_id1 = '$memberHid4'";

    $querySelectResult = @mysqli_query($conn, $querySelect);
    $fetchArr = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult);

    while($fetchArr)
    {
        foreach($fetchArr as $value)

        {
            //echo $value;
            $querySelect2 = "SELECT member_name 
                            FROM friends where friend_id='$value'";
            $querySelectResult2 = @mysqli_query($conn, $querySelectResult2);
            $fetchArr2 = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult2);
            foreach($fetchArr2 as $value)
            {
                //echo $value;
            }       
        }
        $fetchArr = mysqli_fetch_row($querySelectResult);
    }

    header("Location:memberadd.php");
    echo('<a href="memberlist.php">Updated memberlist</a></p></div>');
                //header('Location: friendadd.php'); 

?>
```

Comment: Unable to execute query.

Error code1146:Table '*******_db.member' doesn't exist

Comment: This `echo "".$_SESSION['membername']."<p>Add Member Page</p>";` having 2 double quotes next to each other is invalid. Plus this `echo "<td>"?>` I doubt that will wash. Then there's this `$querySelect2 = "SELECT member_name FROM team ; ";` there are a lot of errors in your code, that's where I gave up. This is a debugging issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no easy to determine the problem, but i found a topic on mysql forum ([MySQL says a table doesn't exist, when it does](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,584744,584744#msg-584744)) that could be related with your problem.

It's important to make sure that there is no other mysql instance on the computer. This could result in your problem too.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful FireVision! It is fine now